# how to call a function from child components to parent component(function is in parent) without including the full component

Tags: reactjs

1. I want to call react toastr from components and want to show in root.js (that contains my full header and footer ). not in component.

   2. if i use `import Root from"./root"`  function is not coming

Comment: is this https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr?

Comment: No .https://github.com/tomchentw/react-toastr this one.

Answer (score 1):

First way its pass call function via props -

```
//in root component
<Child props={this.toast}>
   <ChildOfChild props={this.props.toast}/>
</Child>
```

Another way its to use some global event manager, like [Flux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flux)

And, for my opinion best way its to use [Redux](http://redux.js.org/), based on the Flux :), where you can simply call function from whatever component.

```
dispatch(checkToast('message'));
```

Which will change state of application and display toast on layout component.

UPD: Add example of reduce;

```
export function showToast(message) {
   return {
       type: types.SHOW_TOAST,
       message: message
   }
}

export const actions = {
   showToast
}

const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
   [types.SHOW_TOAST] : (state, action) => {
     return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isShowing: true,
        message: action.message
     })
   }
 }

const initialState = {
   message: null,
   isShowing: false
}

export default function showToastReducer (state = initialState, action) {
  const handler = ACTION_HANDLERS[action.type]

  return handler ? handler(state, action) : state
}
```

And then in your components you can import aciton and call it.

```
import showToast from '../../modules/ShowToast'

....

handleClick = () => {
   dispatch(showToast(message));
}
```

**Attention!**

Its only fast example. For best understanding I recommend yout to read documentation of [Redux](http://redux.js.org/).

Comment: can you please share a example of second opinion

Answer (score 0):

Pass the function in as a prop to the child convent you width to use it in:

**Example:**

In parent component you want to pass `parentFunction` to `<ChildComponent/>`:

```
class Parent extends React.Component{

  ...

  parentFunction(){
    // do something...
  }

  render(){
    return <ChildComponent functionToPass={this.parentFunction} />
  }
}
```

Then you can invoke it in `<ChildComponent />` as follows:

```
class ChildComponent extends React. Component {
  ...
  render(){
    this.props.functionToPass();
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: your means <Root functionName={this.someFunction } /> . but like this all the component "Root" html will also include in my child component . i don't want this . I want to call only a function .

Comment: No it won't. That's the point of passing only the function through as a prop